# Doctrine2 Нужно составить конструкцию для суммы значений полей связанной таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine2

Есть к примеру таблица "table1" со связью с таблицей "table2" "Один ко многим"

Мне нужно сделать расчет суммы для полей всех записей связанной таблицы "table2"

SQL будет примерно таким:

```
SELECT SUM(t2.value1), SUM(t2.value2)
FROM `table1` t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id=t1.table2_id
WHERE t1.status>0 AND t1.user_id=1
```

Помогите составить конструкцию для запроса с помощью Doctrine

**Пришел к такой конструкции:**

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb
        ->select('SUM(t2.value1) AS value1, SUM(t2.value2) AS value2')
        ->from('TestBundle:Table1', 't1')
        ->join('t1.table2', 't2')
        ->where('t1.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('t1.status > 0')
        ->setParameters([
            'user' => $user
        ]);

    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: join нужно так же делать по Entity, внутри Doctrine нет понятия "таблица"

Comment: @Etki `->join('t1.table2', 't2')`  "t1.table2" - это связь, прописанная в Entity. Чем такой способ некорректен?

Comment: Запросы доктрины (DQL) ничего не знают о таблицах, только о сущностях. В этом домене такого понятия просто не существует. Связи прописываются для того, чтобы доктрина смогла построить свой домен, существующий только на сущностях. Это специальная фишка всей доктрины, которая позволяет **не думать о базе данных вообще** (абстрагироваться).